# Best way to amplify the size of a RayCast

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have drawn a circle on the floor. Everything that pass over that circle should be detected. The following code is working:

```
void Update () {
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray landingRay = new Ray (transform.position, Vector3.up);

    // This debug does not seem to work:
    Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, Vector3.up * 50);

    if( Physics.Raycast(landingRay, out hit) ){
        Debug.Log("raycast is working!");
    }
}
```

However, I think the RayCast is only at the center of the Sprite I have drawn (1), so it does not cover the whole circle (2):

[image: current and wanted raycasts]

Is there a optimal way to perform this? Or should I just code several RayCast within the same script?

Comment: You could use a SphereCast with the radius of your circle.
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html

Comment: You would be better off putting in a capsule or sphere collider in trigger mode and use OntriggerEnter() for this. Will also be faster.

Comment: @Reasurria after reading all the answers, I think yours is the best. I looked for a [video where what you said is explained](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/physics/colliders-as-triggers). Feel free to write an answer, or I can do it for you if you prefer ;)

Comment: I'll add an answer shortly hehe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest just putting a sphere or capsule collider (in trigger mode) on your circle and handle the collision in `OnTriggerEnter()`. This should be more efficient than a raycast as well.

You can see the [official video tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/physics/colliders-as-triggers) on the topic here.

Comment: Why do you say a collider is more efficient than a raycast?

Comment: Raycasting is notoriously costly especially inside the Update or FixedUpdate loops is a bad idea. The physics engine is optimized for continuous collision detection. I encourage you to prove me wrong because I don't know this for a fact.

Comment: *"Raycasting is notoriously costly"* Notoriously? I have been using Unity for years and i've never heard such a thing.

Comment: Then I guess you have to use it a few more. https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/physics/physics-best-practices   See the raycasting section.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is a `SphereCast`

```
RaycastHit hit;
float radius = 5f;
float distance = 50f;
Ray landingRay = new Ray (transform.position, Vector3.up);
if (Physics.SphereCast(landingRay, radius, out hit, distance)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very optimal to fire off many raycasts every frame. What you could do is use the center of the circle, and use [Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll.html) or [Physics2D.OverlapCircleAllNonAlloc](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircleNonAlloc.html) to check which colliders are within the range of the circle.

Example

***Attach CircleDetector.cs to the GameObject that has the circle Sprite***

```
public class CircleDetector : MonoBehaviour {

    public float radius = 2;  //This is the radius of the circle Sprite

    void Update () {
        var affectedColliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, radius);
        if(affectedColliders.Length > 0) {
            Debug.Log(string.Format("There were {0} Game Objects within the circle", new object[] { affectedColliders.Length }));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would only work if his game is in 2D, his use of Vector3.Up leads me to think that he is creating a 3D game, so SphereCast of CapsuleCast would be more appropriate.

Comment: The OP mentioned something about raycasting at the center of a sprite, which is why I assumed it'd be 2D. Either way, its jsut a matter of changing the from overlapcircle to overlapsphere

Comment: @Saaru actually it is a 3D game. I "painted" a circle on the floor (a sprite). If something pass over it, it is "activated"

Comment: Wrapping all your suggestions together, I think the comment of  @Reasurria is probably the best option (putting in a capsule or sphere collider in trigger mode and use OntriggerEnter() for this. Will also be faster). Isn't it?

Comment: Yeah I think it will be faster, and if your circle never moves you could mark it static and gain some there as well. 
I think capsule is the shape that makes the most sense though.